# Right way to return true/false in boolean TypeScript/JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm trying to disable all the dates where user already has a booked event on. 
I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime TypeScript and Angular 6. I'm more comfortable with Java but learning some Javascript on my own.

**.TS**

```
    getUserEvents() {
    this._calendarService.getAllEvent().subscribe(res => {
      this.allEvents = res.json();
    });
  }

  filterForbiddenDays() {
    this.allEvents.forEach(d => {
      let day = {
        'start': new Date(d.startDate.value),
        'end': new Date(d.endDate.value)
      };
      this.forbiddenDays.push(day);
    });
  }

  public myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    //return this.forbiddenDays[0].start.getDate() !== d.getDate() && this.forbiddenDays[1].start.getDate() !== d.getDate() // <-- THIS WORKS GREAT
    this.forbiddenDays.filter(data => {
      return data.start.getDate() !== d.getDate() // <-- TRUE SHOULD CHANGE COLOR ON DAY IN CALENDAR
    });
    return false;
  }
```

If I map the forbiddenDays array instead of forEach I can see that i'm getting true for every event in the forbiddenDays, which should change the color on theese days, in the calendar.

But right now myFilter method results in this:
[pic of calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6yRH.png)

What am i doing wrong? I feel like the problem is in myFilter method.

**.HTML**

```
    <div class="example-wrapper datePicker">
        <label class="example-input-wrapper" id="eventInputSuccess">
            <input (click)="filterForbiddenDays()" id="eventInputError" placeholder="Click to choose date"
                (dateTimeInput)="basic.openModal()" [(ngModel)]="dateTimeInput" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt"
                [owlDateTimeFilter]="myFilter" [owlDateTime]="dt"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <owl-date-time #dt [pickerMode]="'dialog'"></owl-date-time>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
return this.forbiddenDays[0].start.getDate() !== d.getDate();
```

results in : [expected result but for all days in my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBOtT.png)

So basically it works great when I specify the index like [0] or [3] etc, but im not sure why it's not working with forEach() or filter()

Comment: Look into the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

Comment: I'm having a bit of an issue understanding the process, what is `myFilter` supposed to do? is it supposed to return a boolean?

Comment: the parameter d: Date returns all dates in the whole calendar and when d is equal to  a date in the forbiddenDays array, it should return a boolean with value true and disable that date in the calendar

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: So basically it works great when I specify the index like [0] or [1] etc, but im not sure why it's not working with forEach() or filter()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `myFilter` allways returns `false`.

The `return` inside  `this.forbiddenDays.forEach()` only breaks out of the current iteration but doesn't cause your function to stop. You have to use `some` or `every`  instead:

```
public myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    return this.forbiddenDays.every(data => {
        return data.start.getDate() !== d.getDate() // <-- TRUE SHOULD CHANGE COLOR ON DAY IN CALENDAR
    });
}
```

this will return `true` only if all elements in the array fulfill `data.start.getDate() !== d.getDate()` and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Returning a value from `forEach` does not break out of the loop.

Comment: I didn't say it does. I said it breaks the iteration, not the loop.

Comment: And I’m saying it breaks nothing. The return value goes nowhere.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Are you familiar with how `.every()` works?

Comment: Of course, but we’re discussing `forEach`. @jhpratt

Comment: Yeah, the return value inside a forEach goes nowhere, but it still breaks the current iteration.

Comment: Run the following: `[1,2,3].forEach(i => { console.log(i); return false; })` You'll see 1 2 3, because the iteration continues.

Comment: I see you are confusing iteration and loop. Run `[1,2,3].forEach(i => { console.log(i); return false;  console.log('this is never print');});`

Comment: You're right. I was confusing the two... which makes be believe that perhaps your answer could be clearer :P

Comment: @Guywhotypesfast that did the trick!

Cheers for the great explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `myFilter` function always returns false. The return in the `forEach` or `filter` callback is *not* going to return the `myFilter` function. It just returns the callback you pass into it, which in this case is pretty pointless.

What I think you want is something like this:

```
public myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  return this.forbiddenDays.every(forbiddenDay => {
    return forbiddenDay.start.getDate() !== d.getDate();
  });
}
```

The `array.every()` method returns `false` if the callback returns `false` for any of the array elements.

You could also write this using a `for..of` loop:

```
public myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  for (let forbiddenDay of this.forbiddenDays) {
    if (forbiddenDay.start.getDate() !== d.getDate()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```